# php oop, pdo and ajax instance issue

Tags: php, ajax, oop, pdo

I'm using php oop with connection pdo.
I need help how to call function from class via ajax

For example, let say that I want to call printBooks by ajax

1. class - entity book:

   ```
   class Book{
       private $id;
       public function setID();
       public function getID();
       public function setName();
       public function getName();
   }
   ```
2. class - controller books:

   ```
   class book_controller{
       private  $books;
       private  $conn;
       public function __construct()
       {
           $database = new Database();
           $db = $database->dbConnection(); 
           $this->conn = $db;
       }
       public function getAllBooks(){
          $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM books");
          $stmt->execute();
          while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
             $b = new book();
             $b->setID($row['id']);
             $b->setName($row['name']);
             $this->books[] = $b;
           }
       }
       public function printBooks(){
         for($i=0; $i<sizeof($this->books);$i++){
           echo $this->books[$i]->getName();
       }
       }
   ```
3. index file

   ```
       <?php
             $bo = new book_controller();
             echo "<button id='callToprintBooks'>";
       ?>
   ```
4. ajax call

   ```
       $.ajax({ 
               url:book_controller.php, 
               type: 'POST', 
               success : function( data ) { 
                   $('#DescModal').html(data); 
                   $('#DescModal').modal("show"); 
               } 
            });
   ```

For simplicity, I want to call printBooks function on button click by ajax from the index.php file after I make the new book_controller instance.
I tried to save the var "$bo" in session but I got an error

> You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances in

I tried to use $_GET call but I don't want to create a new instance (cause then I'll need to build the book array again)

I hope I've been able to explain myself so that you can help me

Comment: `getAllBooks` is completely invalid code

Comment: right, I wrote that it was an example. I've updated the function

Comment: How do you want the books displayed and how do you want them fetched? via AJAX?

Comment: I want to open a modal on button click. here is my ajax code:
$.ajax({
                url:book_controller.php,
                    type: 'POST',
                success : function( data ) {
                    $('#DescModal').html(data);
                    $('#DescModal').modal("show");
                }
            });
As I said, I don't know how to call the function printBook().
I tried to set url: book_controller.php?sendprint=1
and via $_GET['sendprint'] to call the function but then I backed to the starting point, need to create a new instance of book_controller

Answer (score 0):

Create a file **like index.php** which you call new book_controller class' **getAllBooks()** method. But in *getAllBooks()* method at the end of function return $this->books[] as JSON. Then you can call this php file from AJAX and return data as JSON. You can append to html with jQuery's **each()** function

Comment: let said that I changed getAllBooks to return json. in index.php I have variable $b = new book_controller(). I didn't understand from where I called that getAllBooks function

Comment: Do you mean to call getAllBooks in the index.php file? ajax will call to index.php? so every click ajax will call to index.php who create a new instance for every call

Answer (score 0):

getAllBooks:

```
public function getAllBooks(){
   $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM books");
   $stmt->execute();
   while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $b = new book();
      $b->setID($row['id']);
      $b->setName($row['name']);
      $this->books[] = $b;
    }
  return json_encode($this->books[]);
}
```

getBooks.php

```
$controller = new book_controller();
return $controller->getAllBooks();
```

frontend:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'getBooks.php'
  callback: function(data){
     $($.parseJSON(data.books)).each(function(key, value){
       $('#div').append(v.name);
     });
  }
});
```

Then what you have to do is return correct json response in getAllBooks method like:

```
{
  "books": [{
    {"id": 1, "name": "A"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "B"}
   }]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

At first, a general overview of the steps to follow (roughly) for processing the HTTP requests:

- Parse each request through *index.php*. The file *index.php* is the entry point of your MVC application.
- Read the *URI path* from the `REQUEST_URI` value of the `$_SERVER` global variable and the *HTTP method* from `REQUEST_METHOD`.
- Save them together with the values of the other global variables ($_POST, $_GET, etc) into a `Request` object (e.g. an instance of a class named, for example, `Request`).
- Get a router like [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) and build your routes list - read the docs please. Each route is defined as an object with a *HTTP method*, a *pattern*, and a *handler* (e.g. a controller method, e.g. an *action*) as properties.
- Compare the request components (the *HTTP method* and the *URI path* from the `Request` object) with the components of each route object (the *HTTP method* and the *pattern* properties) in the routes list.
- If a match is found, e.g. if the request components are the same as the ones of a route, then create a controller instance and call its *action*, e.g. the corresponding route *handler*.
- Pass the `Request` object as argument, in order to be able to read the POST, GET, etc values from it.
- The controller *action* loads a corresponding template file, renders its content, and returns it.
- Print the returned content (with an `echo [here the content string];`).

---

#### Step 1:

Let's now say that your url is `http://localhost/get-books` and the HTTP method is `GET`. And that, in the routes list of the router, you have added a route object with the following properties:

- HTTP method: `GET`,
- pattern: `/get-books`,
- route handler: `book_controller::getAllBooks`.

After processing all the steps above, the printed content will look something like this:

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#printBooksButton').on('click', function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        /*
                         * This value ('/print-books') corresponds to a
                         * route definition in the predefined routes list.
                         */
                        url: '/print-books',
                        /*
                         * This value ('POST') corresponds to the HTTP method
                         * of a route definition in the predefined routes list.
                         */
                        method: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data: {},
                        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            $('#books').html(response);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('Error. Sorry!');
                            //...
                        },
                        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            //...
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <button type="button" id="printBooksButton" name="printBooksButton" value="printBooks">
                Print all books
            </button>
        </form>

        <div id="books">
            Here comes the books list.
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

#### Step 2:

In the moment of clicking the button `printBooksButton`, the ajax request is executed and parsed throw the `index.php`. But this time the request has the HTTP method `POST` and the url is `http://localhost/print-books`. Going from the fact that you've already defined another route in your routes list with the following properties:

- HTTP method: `POST`,
- pattern: `/print-books`,
- route handler: `book_controller::printBooks`,

and that the general steps in the `index.php` are processed, the *action* `printBooks` of the `book_controller` is executed. But the returned content will not represent a whole webpage structure. Instead it will only be the html code for representing the books list. This html code is "received" by the `success` callback of the ajax request as the `response` argument. Therefore, at last, it's filled into the div with the id `books`.

```
<ul class="books-list">
    <li>Book 1</li>
    <li>Book 2</li>
    <li>Book 3</li>
    <li>Book 4</li>
</ul>
```

---

#### EDIT 1:

**Note:** In my answer I supposed earlier that you are implementing an MVC application. Later, after your question edits, I realized that it may not be 100% the case. But it was too late (regarding the late hour) for me to change anything. So, please answer me to a question: Are all HTTP requests to your application redirected to only one page, e.g. to `index.php`? I will wait an answer and, for now, I will maintain my MVC supposition for the further explanations.

The FastRoute library has the role of a so called ***router***. It essentially does two things:

1. It ***holds a collection of routes*** - defined by the user.
2. It provides a ***routing mechanism***. E.g. it ***dispatches a URI***. E.g. it ***matches*** the components of the request (e.g. the *HTTP method* and the *URI path*) against the components of each route (e.g. the route's *HTTP method* and *pattern*), in order to ***JUST extract the route handler*** (which can be a string like *"controller::action"*, or a closure, etc) ***and the parameters list*** (e.g. a map of placeholder names, as defined in the route's *pattern*, to their values, as given by the user in the *URI*).

So, the router does **NOT** (and should not) call any controller action, but only extracts it from the *handler* property of a matched route object. Based on this controller action definition you, the dev, have to instantiate the controller, call the action (by also passing the values from the parameters list as action arguments) and print the results of this call to the user.

All these things happen in one file, be it `index.php`. So, your controller class is instantiated in `index.php`, **AFTER** the router dispatches the URI and returns the controller name, the action name and the parameters list.

In `index.php` happens also the creation of a database connection (e.g. of a PDO instance in your case), which should be passed as argument to the controller constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. actually, I'm not familiar with fastroute, I didn't understand, fastroute is a kind of switch to call the class's function by http method and pattern? where I need to create the book_controller instance? Do I need to pass the object to fastroute?

Comment: @thinkp You are welcome. I edited my answer with a question and new clarifying explanations. See "EDIT 1".

Comment: @thinkp I was waiting for an answer to my question. Since you didn't answer, did you solved the problem?